# Random BigFloats Julia

Tags: random, julia

Is it possible to generate random numbers of `BigFloat` type uniformly distributed in the interval [0,1)?

I mean, since `rand(BigFloat)` is not available it seems we have to use `BigFloat(rand())` for that ending. However this is not satisfactory for me as  we are generating random `Float64` numbers that are converted to `BigFloats` basically by "adding" a string of zeros, but in essence they are `Float64` random numbers. Is this correct? If yes, is there any special library to generate random numbers with arbitrary precision?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer is similar to @Dan Getz's
but I'm more confidant that it is uniform (honestly I've not done chi^2 test to check, or plots or anything).
@Dan's might be, I'm just not sure.
This answer also takes into account the precision level of BigFloat, which can be adjusted. (Counter-intuitively perhaps some `BigFloat`s can have less precision than normal `Float64`s etc)

```
Base.rand(::Type{BigFloat}) =  get(tryparse(BigFloat, "0." .* join(rand(['0','1'], precision(BigFloat))), 2))
```

Example:

```
julia> rand(BigFloat)
5.775971375531676786209502831045802088939348666270278366043732289527176430673822e-02

julia> rand(BigFloat)
3.061194516436133765062723761241255852372302334681778915000436918803432772307184e-01

julia> rand(BigFloat)
     1.39772524343615633719535808470123032232713877796596771875414945796651457395665e-01
```

Notion is that the BigFloat has a known precision, so we should generate that many random bits.
As we are generating between [0,1), we know the base-2 representation is `0.` something.
So we generate the string in base-2 and parse it in base 2.

Answer (score 6):

For future readers (using Julia 0.7+) you can just do this with `rand(BigFloat)`.
As of https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/22720
(You could certainly port that code to 0.6, and use it under the MIT license).

This is now working on 0.7-dev:

```
julia> rand(BigFloat)
5.381468355278042619008060591939155580805097923053455073547599255767645416051576e-01

julia> rand(BigFloat)
6.678413824545014328186230919629061895976571434256056298415613736582692882364622e-01

julia> rand(BigFloat)
1.388732949711447354224342960598222355426512649106497530016925083999303683268617e-01
```

Answer (score 2):

Is this method good:

```
randbigfloat(n) = 
  ( e = rand(0:n) ; 
    parse(BigFloat, join([rand('0':'9', e)...,'.',rand('0':'9', n-e)...])) )
```

With usage:

```
julia> randbigfloat(10)
3.09424947699999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999e+05

julia> randbigfloat(10)
7.146482599999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999975
```

It might not be the most efficient method though.

Comment: looks horridly expensive and all the 9's don't bode well for truly answering the OP. (hardly better than adding all the the 0's)